# nodeValue is lost when importing element from another DOMDocument object

Tags: php, domdocument

When importing a node from one DOMDocument Object to another DOMDOcument Object, the nodeValue seems to be lost.

**Q1. Anyone knows why?** *(is this a bug?)*

**Q2. How can I fix this?**

---

**Example code:**

```
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$div = $doc1->createElement('div');

$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$span = $doc2->createElement('span', 'Span text');

$spanCopy = $doc1->importNode($span);
$div->appendChild($spanCopy);
$doc1->appendChild($div);

$otp = $doc1->saveHTML();

var_dump($span->nodeValue);
var_dump($spanCopy->nodeValue);
var_dump($otp);
```

**Outputs:**

```
string 'Span text' (length=9)
string '' (length=0)
string '<div><span></span></div>' (length=25)
```

---

**Answer:**

It seems that in order to perform a deep copy, you need to pass true as second argument to importNode.

```
$spanCopy = $doc1->importNode($span, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

It seems that in order to perform a deep copy, you need to pass true as second argument to importNode.

```
$spanCopy = $doc1->importNode($span, true);
```

Comment: I was banging my head in the wall for over 2 hours so I decided to post the question in SO. Figured it out by myself 10 minutes later... Murphy's Law I guess...